# Powershell: run functions in parallel

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

Hello powershell experts,

Below is my **test.ps1** script

```
function HelloNumberOne {Write-Host "Hello Number 1"}
function HelloNumberTwo {Write-Host "Hello Number 2"}
function HelloNumberThree {Write-Host "Hello Number 3"}
function HelloNumberFour {Write-Host "Hello Number 4"}
function HelloNumberFive {Write-Host "Hello Number 5"}
function HelloNumberSix {Write-Host "Hello Number 6"}
```

When I try to run them in parallel as described [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1953753-running-commands-scriptblocks-functions-in-parallel)

```
workflow RunParallel{ 
parallel {

   {HelloNumberOne}   
   {HelloNumberTwo}
   {HelloNumberThree}
   {HelloNumberFour}
   {HelloNumberFive}
   {HelloNumberSix}
  }
}

RunParallel
```

Nothing get's executed. Has anyone been able to execute functions, that are located in same **.ps1** file, in parallel?

Comment: You need to remove the wrapped braces around the function calls in your parallel script block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hsimah, pointed out , you need to  remove curly braces

workflow Run-Parallel{

```
parallel {

    HelloNumberOne   
    HelloNumberTwo
   HelloNumberThree
   HelloNumberFour
   HelloNumberFive
   HelloNumberSix
  }
}
```

These workflows , will not output any data  to host, you need to use variables, if you need to capture output like below

```
workflow Run-Parallel{ 
parallel {

   $a=  HelloNumberOne   
    HelloNumberTwo
  }
}

$a
```

Comment: Thanks @TheGameiswar for your answer. It did work. Interesting thing is: even not declaring a variable, the output is still printed at the host.

Comment: wow,strange..with the given example, i am not able to get any output